# Is it dangerous to use debug version Flash Player?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-player

I installed debug version Flash Player on my computer to develope a Flash application.

I am using debug version Flash Player for debugging my application.
But I also use it while browsing other web sites.

But debug version Flash Player isn't be updated automatically.
Is it dangerous to use debug version Flash Player because Flash Player which is not latest has security problem.

Comment: this is probably better asked at superuser

Comment: @ChrisWue Thanks. But I think this is problem for developer of flash application. 
Can superuser answer this question?
And isn't this question about `software tools commonly used by programmers` which is written on the faq of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If your Debug Flash Player isn't updating automatically then yes, it is a bit dangerous while it is behind, but if you keep it updated manually then you're the same as far as that's concerned.
Also, the debug Flash Player is noticeably slower than the non-debug version. If you are concerned you can have both installed in Chrome and switch which one is enabled back and forth fairly easily, or use different browsers for debug and non-debug versions.